# How to make progress bar on Ajax Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am using `Ajax Upload JS 3.5` is there a way to make a progress upon uploading of `image / File` ?. All I see in my net is by using the `<input type="file">` button and my project is not a bootstrap.

Here is my currently code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var extension = "";
var btnUploadDrvr = $("#btnFitaDocBrowse");
var hidFilenameDrvr = $("#imgFitaDoc");
var hidDoccFrame = $("#frmFitaDoc");


InitAjaxUpload(btnUploadDrvr, hidFilenameDrvr, hidDoccFrame );

function InitAjaxUpload(btnUpload, imgHolder, hidDoccFrame) {
    new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
        action: '../UploadDownload/UploadLocalPic',
        data: '',
        name: 'uploadfile',
        onSubmit: function (file, ext) {
            extension = ext[0];
            if (!(ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif|pdf|PDF)$/.test(ext))) {
                alert("File format is not supported.");
                return false;
            }
        },
        onComplete: function (file, response) {
            //Add uploaded file to list
            if (response !== "failed") {
                    $("#frmFitaDoc").attr('src', 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + response);                   
            } 
        }
    });
}
});
```

And I saw [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GvdSy/) can this be possible to embed in my code?.

Comment: Instead of checking the filetypes with js, why not just add the `accept` attribute and get it taken care of for u and the user...

Comment: Make a link of your `Ajax Upload JS 3.5`...

Comment: I'm going to say probably not supported, you would need to craft your own xhr add the progress listener and do everything yourself, you don't need a lib for this uploading stuff using `new FormData(formElm)` you can go a long way with just doing it yourself

Comment: @Endless the big problem is I am new to web programming.